# Representing a stochastic integral as product of a unknown random variable and a standard normal random variable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, (\mathcal F_t)_{t\geq0},\mathbb P)$ where $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F_t)_{t\geq0}$ is generated by $B=(B_t)_ { t \geq 0}$ a standard brownian motion starting at zero.

Also, consider a process $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ given by

$$ \varepsilon_t,=\sqrt{2}\int_0^t\phi(s) \sigma_s^2 dB_s \ , \quad\forall t \in [0,1] $$
where $\phi \in \mathcal C^1([0,1])$ deterministic and $ (\sigma_t)$ a progressively measurable process.

I am interested in representing this process at time $t=1$ as a product  between two random variables 
$$ \varepsilon_1 =U\xi $$ 
where $U$ is a $\mathcal F_1$- measurable r.v. whose the law is to be determined and $\xi$ is a standard gaussian variable independent of $U$.

I have no idea how to start to show that, if it's possible in this case. Since $\sigma$ is a process whose his law is totally unknown , it seems strange for a priori be able to determine U ( I insist, if it's possible).

> **Edit:**  Following the suggestion given by Did in his answer. IF we define  $$ \xi =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\int_0^1\phi(s)^2 \sigma_s^4 ds}} \int_0^t\phi(s) \sigma_s^2 dB_s $$
>
> and  $$U= \sqrt{2\int_0^1\phi(s)^2 \sigma_s^4 ds}$$
>
> Why should $\xi$ be normal distributed? The fact is totally clear whenever $\sigma$ is deterministic however in this case $\sigma$ is not.

All advices are appreciated.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: This is NOT my suggestion, please read better.

Comment: @Did : Sorry for my typo. I replaced $dB_s$ for $ds$ for $U$ and the normalization coefficient of $\xi$. Please confirm if that is all or if I do misunderstood your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: The problem was indeed $dB_s$ instead of $ds$.

Answer (score 2):

When $\sigma$ and $B$ are independent, a solution is $$ U=\sqrt{2\cdot\int_0^1\phi(t)^2\sigma_t^4\,\mathrm dt}.$$
When $\sigma$ is progressively measurable with respect to the filtration of $B$, the same solution might apply in the sense that $U\xi$ could be distributed like $\varepsilon_1$. As first steps in this direction, note that, for every real $x$, by independence of $(U,\xi)$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}\mid U]=\mathrm e^{-x^2U^2/2},
$$
hence
$$
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}]=E[\mathrm e^{-x^2U^2/2}].
$$
On the other hand, $U^2=\langle\varepsilon\rangle_1$ hence
$$
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix\varepsilon_1+x^2U^2/2}]=1.
$$

Comment: I gave up this idea wich was my only one by the way since I prematurely guessed $\xi=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{\int_0^1\phi(t)^2\sigma_t^4 dt} } \int_0^1\phi(t)\sigma_t^2 dB_t$ would not be normal distributed. Thank you very much!

Comment: I feel I misunderstood something in the theory because I still don't see why it's normal distributed. Can you help me, please ?

Comment: Of course, this U is very far from being normal. What made you think it should be?

Comment: not $U$ but the $\xi$ I defined in the first comment

Comment: The answer is not obvious. See Edit.

Comment: I believe it's $ E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}\mid U]=\mathrm e^{-x^2U^2/2}$ and $E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}]=E[\mathrm e^{-x^2U^2/2}]$. Also I don't understand how do you get the last sentence, which must also have a typo as the previous I've cited by the way. Could you say what you've done at the end and/ or reformulate your conclusion please? Many thank's

Comment: Post modified. $ $

Comment: I think it is still incorrect. $
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}\mid U]=\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2U^2}{2}},
$ and not $
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}\mid U]=\mathrm e^{-x^2U^2}
$. Also, $
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}]=E[\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2U^2}{2}}]$ in place of $
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixU\xi}]=E[\mathrm e^{-x^2U^2}]
$. However, I still can't see how to conclude.

Comment: Also you've corrected the only identity that was correct before witch was $
E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix\varepsilon_1-x^2U^2/2}]=1.
$ no $+$.

Comment: You think that $E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix\varepsilon_1-x^2U^2/2}]=1$?

Comment: OK my mistake. I forgot the $i$. But, still can't see how to conclude from there.

Comment: Could you also please take a look on this two other questions? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676547/estimation-of-a-itos-semi-martingale-linear-functional  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676894/asymptotic-result-on-quadratic-variation-of-a-semi-martingale-linear-functional

Answer (score 0):

An easy counter-example :   $ 2 \int_0^1  B_s dB_s = B_1^2  -1$ which is not a 
symmetric random variable  contrary to the product $U \xi$  with    $\xi$  a centered
gaussian random variable independent from $U$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample since one would have to consider $\phi(t)\sigma^2_t=B_t$, which is impossible for sign reasons.