# Estimation of a Ito's semi-martingale linear functional

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, estimation, parameter-estimation

**Could someone check my solution for the following problem please? Or maybe  propose a smarter/shorter solution.**

> Consider a stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ defined in a
>   filtred probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F , (\mathcal F
>  ^W_t)_{t\in [0,1]}, \mathbb P)$ (where $W$ is a standard brownian
>   motion and $(\mathcal F ^W_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ is its natural filtration)
>   satisfying
>
> $$ X_t = X_0+\int _0^t b_s ds + \int _0^t \sigma_s dW_s \quad \mathbb
>  P-\text{a.e.}\ , \forall t \in [0,1]$$
>
> where $b=(b_s (\omega))_{t\in [0,1]}$ and $\sigma=(\sigma_s
>  (\omega))_{t\in [0,1]}$ are defined on the same filtered probability
>   space , progressively mesuables and verify:
>
> (H1) (Uniformly bounded) There is $C>0$ such that $\sup_{s\in
>  [0,1]}(|b_s(\omega)|+|\sigma_s(\omega)|)\leq C$,
>
> (H2) $\mathbb E [(\sigma_s^2- \sigma_t^2)^2]\leq \varpi(t-s), \quad
>  \varpi(h) \rightarrow 0  \text{ as } h \rightarrow 0$
>
> In this context we observe $(X_0,X_{1/n}, \cdots, X_{i/n}, \cdots ,
>  X_1)$ ($n \in \mathbb N ^*)$ and we are interested in estimates the
>   linear functional
>
> $$ \Lambda(\phi)_t := \int _0 ^t \phi(s) \sigma^2_s ds, \quad t\in
>  [0,1]$$
>
> whrere $\phi \in \mathcal C^0 ([0,1]; \mathbb R)$ by
>   $$\widehat\Lambda_n(\phi)_t := \sum_{i=1}
>  ^{[nt]}\phi(\frac{i-1}{n})(X_{i/n}-X_{(i-1)/n})^2$$
>
> Now I want to show that indeed  $\widehat\Lambda_n(\phi)_t
>  \overset{\mathbb P}\longrightarrow  \Lambda(\phi)_t $.

I started by supposing $b\equiv 0$ in other to focus on the main problem and thy to show that it converges in $\mathbb L ^2(\mathbb P)$

$\widehat\Lambda_n(\phi)_t -  \Lambda(\phi)_t =\sum_{i=1} ^{[nt]}\left[\phi(\frac{i-1}{n})(X_{i/n}-X_{(i-1)/n})^2 -\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \phi(s) \sigma^2_s ds\right] + \int ^{t} _{[nt]/n} \phi(s) \sigma^2_s ds$

Then consider

$$ M^{i,n} := \phi(\frac{i-1}{n})(X_{i/n}-X_{(i-1)/n})^2 -\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \phi(s) \sigma^2_s ds$$ 
Ito's lemma implies that 
$$ M^{i,n} = \int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \left( \int ^s _{(i-1)/n}2\phi(\frac{i-1}{n})\sigma_u dW_u \right)\sigma_s dW_s + \int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \phi(\frac{i-1}{n})\sigma^2_s ds -\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \phi(s) \sigma^2_s ds$$

then let be

$$A^{i,n} := \int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \left( \int ^s _{(i-1)/n}2\phi(\frac{i-1}{n})\sigma_u dW_u \right)\sigma_s dW_s $$

$$B^{i,n} :=\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \phi(\frac{i-1}{n})\sigma^2_s ds -\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \phi(s) \sigma^2_s ds$$

Thus we have $ (M^{i,n})^2 \leq 2 \left( A^{i,n}\right)^2 + 2\left(B^{i,n}\right)^2$ and taking expected values both sides

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[ (M^{i,n})^2 ]&\leq 2 \mathbb E\left[\left( A^{i,n}\right)^2\right] + 2\mathbb E\left[\left(B^{i,n}\right)^2\right] \leq \frac{K}{n^2}
\end{align}

whith $K = 12C^4 (\sup_{s\in [0,1]}\phi(s))^2$, since 
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\left( A^{i,n}\right)^2\right] &= \mathbb E\left[\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \left( \int ^s _{(i-1)/n}2\phi(\frac{i-1}{n})\sigma_u dW_u \right)^2 \sigma_s^2 ds\right] \\
&=\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n}  \mathbb E\left[\left( \int ^s _{(i-1)/n}2\phi(\frac{i-1}{n})\sigma_u \sigma_s dW_u \right)^2 \right]ds \\
&=\int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n}  \mathbb E\left[ \int ^s _{(i-1)/n}4\phi^2(\frac{i-1}{n})\sigma_u^2 \sigma_s^2 du  \right]ds \\
&\leq 4 C^4 (\sup_{s\in [0,1]}\phi(s))^2 \int _{(i-1)/n} ^{i/n} \int ^s _{(i-1)/n} du ds = \frac{2C^4 (\sup_{s\in [0,1]}\phi(s))^2} {n^2} [i^2 -(i-1)^2
 -2(i-1)]\\
&\leq \frac{2C^4 (\sup_{s\in [0,1]}\phi(s))^2} {n^2}
\end{align}

(by Ito's isometry in §1,3, Fubini's theorem in §2 and (H1) in §4) and

$$B^{i,n} \leq \frac{2 \sup_{s \in [0,1]}\phi(s) C^2}{n}$$
(by (H1)).

We conclude by remarking that

\begin{align}
\left|\widehat\Lambda_n(\phi)_t -  \Lambda(\phi)_t \right|^2 &\leq 2\sum_{i=1} ^{[nt]}\left( M^{i,n}\right)^2 +2 \left(\int ^{t} _{[nt]/n} \phi(s) \sigma^2_s ds\right)^2\\
&\leq 2\sum_{i=1} ^{[nt]}\left( M^{i,n}\right)^2 + 2 C^4 \left(\sup_{s\in [0,1]} \phi(s)\right)^2 \frac{(nt -[nt])}{n}\\
&\leq 2\sum_{i=1} ^{[nt]}\left( M^{i,n}\right)^2 +  \frac{2 C^4 \left(\sup_{s\in [0,1]} \phi(s)\right)^2}{n}
\end{align}
and taking expected value both sides

\begin{align}
 \parallel\widehat\Lambda_n(\phi)_t -  \Lambda(\phi)_t\parallel^2_{\mathbb L^2(\mathbb P)} =\mathbb E \left[\left|\widehat\Lambda_n(\phi)_t -  \Lambda(\phi)_t\right|^2 \right] \leq \frac{K'}{n} \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n\rightarrow \infty
\end{align}

where $ K' = 14 C^4 \left(\sup_{s\in [0,1]} \phi(s)\right)^2$.
The convergence in probability is consequence of the convergence in $\mathbb L^2(\mathbb P)$